# can't make python code pause for five seconds

Tags: python, tkinter, wait, sleep, pause

I want a pause of 5 secs between drawing the first line and second line. But neither of the commented options work when I uncomment them.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

window = Tk()
window.title("window title")
frame = Frame(window)
frame.grid()
    
canvas = Canvas(frame, bg = "yellow", height = 400, width = 600)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_line(20, 10, 80, 30)
# window.after(5000)
# time.sleep(5)
canvas.create_line(50, 50, 100, 200)

window.mainloop()
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you uncomment them? Errors? Or just doesn't work as intended...

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582282/python-time-sleep-method-in-canvas)

Comment: Nothing happens for five seconds, and then the window appears with both lines drawn (no delay between them).
That's what happens in *both* cases: window.after(5000) *and* time.sleep(5)

Comment: Check out the question I linked then.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. That seems to work now. I need a canvas.update() call between the two create_line() calls.

Comment: Using `canvas.update()` in a loop is definitely not a best practice. In such a simple program it's fairly harmless, but can have unexpected side effects in a more complex application. It's a bad habit to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pause the mainloop, and even if you could, your TopLevel window is a child of the root so it would pause. You could try grab_set() method on the top_level. Alternatively, you can disable multiple widgets in a single for loop by accessing them through their parent.

Comment: _"You can't pause the mainloop"_ - that's not true. As long as any other code is running, `mainloop` isn't running.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley then I guess I was wrong on that. Can you please provide me a detailed explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is single-threaded, which means it can only do one thing at a time. `time.sleep(5)` and `window.after(5000)` both cause the entire application to sleep for five seconds. While it's sleeping it can't do anything else. That includes the fact that it can't refresh the window or anything in the window.

What you need to do instead is use `after` to schedule the drawing of the second line to five seconds in the future, which allows `mainloop` to run in the interim. The simplest modification in this specific example would be something like this:

```
canvas.create_line(20, 10, 80, 30)
window.after(5000, canvas.create_line, 50, 50, 100, 100)

window.mainloop()
```

This will create the first line, schedule the second line to be drawn, and then start the event loop. With the event loop started, tkinter will draw the window and draw the first line. About five seconds later it will call `canvas.create_line` with the given arguments.